# Conditional JOIN in Apache Beam SqlTransform Python SDK

Tags: python-3.x, sdk, left-join, apache-beam

I cannot find the working syntax in SqlTransform for left joining two PCollections. My code is (Python SDK):

```
class Products(typing.NamedTuple):
        product: str
        name: str
        code3: str
        
    class Groups(typing.NamedTuple):
        code1: str
        name1: str
        code2: str
        name2: str
        code3: str
        name3: str
    beam.coders.registry.register_coder(Products, beam.coders.RowCoder)
    beam.coders.registry.register_coder(Groups, beam.coders.RowCoder)

    with beam.Pipeline() as p:
    
        products = p | 'ReadProducts' >> beam.io.ReadFromText(data_path + 'products.csv', skip_header_lines=1)\
                     | beam.Map(lambda line: line.split(';'))\
                     | beam.Map(lambda x: beam.Row(product = str(x[0]), name = str(x[1]), code3 = str(x[2])))#.with_output_types(Products)
        
       
        groups = p | 'ReadGroups' >> beam.io.ReadFromText(data_path + 'groups.csv', skip_header_lines=1)\
                     | beam.Map(lambda line: line.split(';'))\
                     | beam.Map(lambda x: beam.Row(code1 = str(x[0]), name1 = str(x[1]), code2 = str(x[2]), name2 = str(x[3]), code3 = str(x[4]), name3 = str(x[5])))#.with_output_types(Groups)
        # JOIN
        dict_ = {'products':products, 'groups':groups}
        dict_ | SqlTransform("""
                  SELECT *
                  FROM products LEFT JOIN groups ON products.code3 = groups.code3;""")
```

> The error:
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in 
> 18     # JOIN
> 19     dict_ = {'products':products, 'groups':groups}
> ---> 20     dict_ | SqlTransform("""
> 21               SELECT *
> 22               FROM products LEFT JOIN groups ON products.code3 = groups.code3;""")
>
> ~/HDD2/WORK/PROJECTS/Apache_Beam/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apache_beam/transforms/ptransform.py
> in **ror**(self, left, label)
> 570     pvalueish = _SetInputPValues().visit(pvalueish, replacements)
> 571     self.pipeline = p
> --> 572     result = p.apply(self, pvalueish, label)
> 573     if deferred:
> 574       return result
>
> ................
>
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by: o
>
> rg.apache.beam.vendor.calcite.v1_20_0.org.apache.calcite.sql.parser.SqlParseException:
> Encountered "LEFT JOIN groups" at line 3, column 29. Was expecting one
> of:
> "NATURAL" ...
> "JOIN" ...
> "INNER" ...
> "LEFT" "OUTER" ...
> "LEFT" "JOIN" ...
> "LEFT" "JOIN"  ...
> "LEFT" "JOIN" <QUOTED_IDENTIFIER> ...
> "LEFT" "JOIN" <BACK_QUOTED_IDENTIFIER> ...
> "LEFT" "JOIN" <BRACKET_QUOTED_IDENTIFIER> ...
> "LEFT" "JOIN" <UNICODE_QUOTED_IDENTIFIER> ...
> "LEFT" "JOIN" "LATERAL" ...
> "LEFT" "JOIN" "(" ...
> "LEFT" "JOIN" "UNNEST" ...
> "LEFT" "JOIN" "TABLE" ...
> "," ...
> "CROSS" ...
> "OUTER" ...
> "EXTEND" ...
> "(" ...

Comment: I don't know if this matters, but maybe you can try the "USING" clause? i.e. """SELECT * FROM products LEFT JOIN groups USING(code3)"""

Comment: Already used it but it didn't work, neither the Calcite SQL syntax. Couldn't find other syntax examples.